# Label problems in TicTacToe

Tags: java, netbeans

I can't seem to get my code to display the scores and totals of my TicTacToe game in NetBeans. How do I display these variables, as well as update the player score and add to the player total?

Here's what I've got so far:

```
public class TicTacToe extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{

    private static boolean xTurn = true;
    public Player player1;
    public Player player2;
    private static JButton[] buttonArray = new JButton[9];

    private static int[] winsArray =
    {
        7, 56, 448, 73, 146, 292, 273, 84
    };

    public TicTacToe()//constructor
    {

        player1 = new Player(GameUtil.promptPlayersName());
        player2 = new Player(GameUtil.promptPlayersName());
        //set marker
        player1.setPlayerMarker('X');
        player2.setPlayerMarker('O');

        JPanel gameBoard = new JPanel();
        gameBoard.setLayout(new GridLayout(6, 3));

        int myBinary = 1;
        for (int index = 0; index < 9; index++)
        {
            buttonArray[index] = new JButton("");
            buttonArray[index].addActionListener(this);
            buttonArray[index].setActionCommand("" + myBinary);
            buttonArray[index].setText("");
            gameBoard.add(buttonArray[index]);
            myBinary = myBinary * 2;
        }
        //labels
        gameBoard.add(new JLabel("Players"));
        gameBoard.add(new JLabel("Score"));
        gameBoard.add(new JLabel("Total"));
        gameBoard.add(new JLabel("X"));
        gameBoard.add(new JLabel("" + player1.getPlayerScore()));
        gameBoard.add(new JLabel("" + player1.getPlayerTotal()));
        gameBoard.add(new JLabel("O"));
        gameBoard.add(new JLabel("" + player2.getPlayerScore()));
        gameBoard.add(new JLabel("" + player2.getPlayerTotal()));

        this.add(gameBoard);
        this.setSize(400, 400);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        System.out.println(player1.getPlayerName());
        System.out.println(player2.getPlayerName());

    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)//listener
    {
        System.out.println(e);
        JButton pressedButton = (JButton) e.getSource();

        {

            if (pressedButton.getText() == "")//X stays X & O stays O
            {

                if (xTurn)
                {
                    pressedButton.setText("X");
                    if (player1.getPlayerMarker() == 'X')
                    {
                        player1.addPlayerTotal(Integer.parseInt(e.getActionCommand()));
                        System.out.println(player1.getPlayerTotal());//debug
                    } else
                    {
                        player2.addPlayerTotal(Integer.parseInt(e.getActionCommand()));
                        System.out.println(player2.getPlayerTotal());//debug
                    }
                    xTurn = false;
                } else
                {

                    pressedButton.setText("O");
                    if (player1.getPlayerMarker() == 'O')
                    {
                        player1.addPlayerTotal(Integer.parseInt(e.getActionCommand()));
                        System.out.println(player1.getPlayerTotal());//debug
                    } else
                    {
                        player2.addPlayerTotal(Integer.parseInt(e.getActionCommand()));
                        System.out.println(player2.getPlayerTotal());//debug
                    }
                    xTurn = true;
                }
            }
        }
        //debug
        System.out.println("Player 1: " + player1.getPlayerName() + " Total: " + player1.getPlayerTotal());
        System.out.println("Player 2: " + player2.getPlayerName() + " Total: " + player2.getPlayerTotal());
        //check if either player won
        System.out.println("P1 Winner: " + check4Winner(player1.getPlayerTotal()));
        System.out.println("P2 Winner: " + check4Winner(player2.getPlayerTotal()));
        //if either player won
        if(check4Winner(player1.getPlayerTotal()))
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, player1.getPlayerName() + " WON");
            System.out.println(player1.getPlayerName() + " WON");//debug
            updatePlayerScore(player1);
            resetGame();
        }
        if(check4Winner(player2.getPlayerTotal()))
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, player2.getPlayerName() + " WON");
            System.out.println(player2.getPlayerName() + " WON");//debug
            updatePlayerScore(player2);
            resetGame();
        }



        //System.out.println("OK");
    }

    public void resetGame()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        {
            buttonArray[i].setText("");
        }
        player1.setPlayerTotal(0);
        player2.setPlayerTotal(0);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        //TicTacToe game = new TicTacToe();
        new TicTacToe().setVisible(true);
    }

    public static boolean check4Winner(int total)
    {
      for (int i = 0; i < winsArray.length; i += 1) 
      {
          if ((winsArray[i] & total) == winsArray[i])
          {
              return true;
          }
      }
      return false;
    }

    public void updatePlayerScore(Player score)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        {
        player1.updatePlayerScore(+ 1);
        player2.updatePlayerScore(+ 1);
        }
    }
```

Comment: These labels: gameBoard.add(new JLabel("Players"));
    gameBoard.add(new JLabel("Score"));
    gameBoard.add(new JLabel("Total"));
    gameBoard.add(new JLabel("X"));
    gameBoard.add(new JLabel("" + player1.getPlayerScore()));
    gameBoard.add(new JLabel("" + player1.getPlayerTotal()));
    gameBoard.add(new JLabel("O"));
    gameBoard.add(new JLabel("" + player2.getPlayerScore()));
    gameBoard.add(new JLabel("" + player2.getPlayerTotal()));

Comment: SO isn't a discussion board.  If you have additional information that is relevant to your question, [edit] your question and add it there, not as a comment.